Book about a homeless guy who interacts with an intelligent rat -- new or something from long ago?
Note: I am not sure, unless you find the synopsis intriguing, why knowing which book I read that made me wonder if the plot was original is important  -- I am looking for a potential match between what I remember and an actual book or short story. But if someone is interested the title is as mentioned The Rider and it is an audiobook narrated by Berger -- there are many sites carrying the book and if you search on "Berger" "The Rider" and "audiobook" you should get hits and you can decide which website to visit because I do not want to advertise any particular vendor.
I encountered a book The Rider (not a book about cycling) that has a plot I believe I read before, and maybe before 2000 but probably called something else.
The plot, basically about an office worker who loses his job and ends up living in the subway and ignored by other people befriends an intelligent rat, sounds familiar. I know Willard was a movie which involved a human and a smart rat, but I do not think it was first a book. Even if it was, Willard was a youngster or young man and he was not homeless.
Maybe I am remembering the movie as having been a book but not to say the book in question is the result of plagiarism, but the plot is very familiar.
I am asking if anyone can identify a potential book written perhaps as early as the 1960s or as late as the mid 1970s with that sort of plot.

I'm confused, you say the book was called The Rider but you want us to identify it?

No, I saw a book online, an audiobook called The Rider -- I believe I read a book/story/novella with the same or very similar plot many years, decades perhaps, ago. I am asking if anyone knows if such a book exists and it almost certainly would NOT be called The Rider. So just looking for a book or story or movie maybe with that plot.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratman%27s_Notebooks

@Paulie_D: I did not know Willard was based on a book or did not remember and indeed I might have read that book (the date it was written is about the right time) but the plot is different as I mentioned.

Would you, perhaps, consider linking to the audio book? The only results I can find for book "the rider" link to  Tim Krabbé's book about cycling, and you seem to indicate that this isn't the topic of your recent encounter.

I don't see anything in https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ResourcefulRodent

Maybe this The Rider?

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/20708781-the-twyning involves a young boy and his rat.

@freeman: No rats in it, right?

@FuzzyBoots: No homelessness apparently and too new.

@freeman: Interestingly Krabbe is also a very good chess player besides a serious cyclist. But yes, that is not the book. I had the link to the "correct" The Rider -- since I purchased it, i will have to look up the details again after i get home from work.

Stretch, but if you're looking for a really old story, maybe Flowers for Algernon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowers_for_Algernon)? It was written as a short story in 1959 and a novel in 1966, and involves a very low-IQ person interacting with a very high-IQ rat. He's not homeless or an office worker though (he's a factory worker).

@nneonneo: of course a great book but really not close since Charley is mentally handicapped but not homeless and in fact in those days might have been institutionalized but not homeless. The sad thing today is the fact that a large percentage of the homeless are not lazy but have mental illness or simply have such low IQs that they can't manage by themselves. Very unfortunate situation indeed.

I wonder if you are finding similarities between the described text and the 1996 novel Neverwhere by Neil Gaiman? In Neverwhere the protagonist is an office worker who loses his job (and flat, and fiancé) but discovers a magical underworld in the London Underground, sewers, rooftops, and related interstitial spaces of the city. He and a human companion are guided by a rat at one point, but I would not exactly describe them (the rat and the humans) as friends. The novel was an adaptation of a 1996 BBC TV miniseries screenplay by the same name, so the time frame fits "before 2000", but definitely not as early as the '70s.

I think Gaiman is a remarkable writer: both prolific and technically very good, a sophisticated writer who can write not just for children and adults but even stories that seem to me to work for both at the same time.

"The novel was an adaptation of a 1996 BBC TV miniseries screenplay by the same name" - Silly question, but were you aware that the miniseries was also written by Gaiman - so his book was an adaptation of his own work?

@AJM Yes. Yes, I was.
